# Non-Interacting Electrons in a Periodic Potential

Tags: condensed-matter

I am reading *Condensed Matter Physics, Second edition* by Michael P. Marder ([Link](http://library.lol/main/5C7EF76AC33A06D04EE3FBFEFC79538C)). There I got stuck in the eq $(7.7)$.
The concept is that according to the Fourier theorem, every periodic function
can be written as a sum of all the complex exponential functions $\exp(ikx)$ that
share the same period. So why is the coefficient of $\exp(ikx)$ a function of $q'$? Cannot it be a constant?

> $$\psi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt L}\sum_{q'}\psi(q')e^{iq'x}\tag{7.7}$$ The sum over $q'$ is the same as summing over $l'$ with $q'=2\pi l'/L$. The factor of $\sqrt L$ foxes normalization.

Comment: It _could_ be a constant but it doesn't have to be. Why do you think it should be?

Comment: Have you used Fourier series / transforms before?

Comment: Thanks, I got it. They can be a function of some parameter because when we calculate the coefficient of $exp(iq'x)$ by integrating it over the space(x-coordinate). We will be left with $q'$.